# Gulp: Watch all subdirectories with the use of **

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

When setting up a watch on a network drive, I am unable to use ** to find all subdirectories. The error I get has been reported and as far as I can tell it's a known issue with Gulp that isn't yet fixed. The code I'm using is very basic and is just intended to test that a watch is working:

```
gulp.task('watch', function(){
    var watcher = gulp.watch('**/*.js');
    watcher.on('change', function(event){
      console.log('File: ' + event.path + ' changed');
    });
});
```

My question is, as I can't get ** working on a network drive, is there an alternative that would allow me to have Gulp check all subdirectories on a watch? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked to see if any of the gulp plugins that supply similar functionality might avoid the issue? For example this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-watch

Comment: I did give gulp-watch a try actually - but I must admit I wasn't very persistent. I'll try a bit harder with gulp-watch and see if I can get it working. My main concern was that the examples they list still use **, which is what is causing the error

Comment: For reference, the error I get is: Error: ENOTSUP: operation not supported on socket, scandir

Comment: Yes, this is true it does us the same syntax. However if you look in the package.json of gulp-watch you will notice that they have a dev depency on a package called glob where as gulp itself does not. This leads me to believe that gulp may have their own implementation of "globbing" whereas gulp-watch uses a different package. It's there that I am hoping (for you :D) that you might get a better result.

Comment: Another thing, have you tried mapping your network location as a local drive and then running your task with that as your cwd?

Comment: I haven't yet tried mapping it locally no - I think perhaps I'll try gulp-watch, and then if that doesn't work, I'll give the mapping a go. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: If I'm completely honest I'd try mapping the drive first. That has a good chance of working for a lot less effort ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the cumulation of my comments as an answer :P

Have you checked to see if any of the gulp plugins that supply similar functionality might avoid the issue? For example this one: http://npmjs.com/package/gulp-watch

If you look in the package.json of gulp-watch you will notice that they have a dev depency on a package called glob where as gulp itself does not. This leads me to believe that gulp may have their own implementation of "globbing" whereas gulp-watch uses a different package. It's there that I am hoping (for you :D) that you might get a better result.

Another thing, have you tried mapping your network location as a local drive and then running your task with that as your cwd? I'd try mapping the drive first. That has a good chance of working for a lot less effort ;)

Comment: After trying this out, it was a valid solution to the problem. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Glad to hear you found a solution. Happy to have helped. Also thanks for taking the time to come back and recognise my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by replacing the `'**/*.js'` to `**/**/*.js`. This will find any javascript files you have.

Comment: Sorry perhaps I misphrased the question. ** does not work at all for me, perhaps because I'm trying to use it over a networked drive. I did try your suggestion but it gave the same error.